# D-Sub port not working on Windows 7 (Intel onboard gigabyte)

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors

Iv been using my HDMI slot to run a 24" monitor and all was well. I borrowed a 17" monitor from work to run a dual screen set up, plugged it into the d-sub port and nothing happened. Checked the new monitor on a laptop and it worked fine. Next i unplugged my 24" from the HDMI slot and tried that in the D-sub and nothing happened.

Can anyone help?

Comment: what kind of graphics card are you using? onboard, which mainboard? or dedicated, which card exactly?

Comment: It sounds like the d-sub port on the motherboard is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your computer/video-card setup, you might need to manually enable the second display port in your Windows Display Properties

From [Windows Support Site:](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Move-windows-between-multiple-monitors)

> 1. Open **Screen Resolution** by clicking the **Start** button [image: Start orb image, taken from linked MS page], clicking **Control Panel**, and then, under `Appearance and Personalization**, clicking **Adjust screen resolution**.
> 2. Click the drop-down list next to **Multiple displays**, click **Extend these displays**, and then click **OK**.
>
>    [image: Screenshot of drop-down, taken from linked MS page]
>    <sub>*The Multiple displays option appears only when Windows detects more than one monitor connected to your PC.*</sub>
>
> **Note:**
>
> - If you don't see an option named **Multiple displays** in your display
>     settings, then Windows isn't detecting a second monitor plugged into
>     your desktop computer. Or, it is not detecting an external monitor
>     plugged into your laptop. When Windows detects this monitor, it will
>     appear in the drop-down list next to **Display**. If you don't see it
>     listed there, try clicking **Detect**.
> - Make sure the monitor you want to extend your desktop to is turned on
>     and plugged into the correct video port on your computer. You might
>     also need to select the correct source labeled on your monitor's
>     controls to ensure the monitor is using the correct video port. For
>     more information, check the manual for your monitor or go to the
>     manufacturer's website.